# Which one is better for game development? Jpanel or jframe?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to develop a game with java jframe. every thing with event/ graphics is doing really good. But when i am trying to add buttons, menus etc in jFrame i am having trouble. I see lot other java graphics works with Jpane. I am not a pro in java, just sneaking around. So can any one help me out which one should i use?

Comment: Please provide at least on line of your code where you adding elements to JFrame. What exactly does not work fine for you? What is trouble?

Comment: You will probably need a JFrame. I am not expert in Swing but I would set a `LayoutManager` to `JFrame.getContentPane();` and add the components to `JFrame.getContentPane();`.

Comment: You should always use a JPanel for you custom painting and other components. Then you ADD the panel to the JFrame.

Answer (score 5):

`JFrame` is the top level window which contains a title bar with some controls to close/minimize the window. It also contains the menu bar.

[image] .. [image]

Inside the `JFrame`, there is one big `JPanel` called `content pane`. The `JPanel` is a container that can contain swing components like `JButton`, `JLabel`, `JTextField`, ... etc. `JPanel` can contain nested `JPanel`s as well.

Note that there multiple layers behind and in front of the content pane layer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Eng.Fouad's answer, here is a simple demonstration of this concept, along with lines being printed to the JPanel.

Here is the class that creates a JFrame and add a JPanel to it.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawPanelTest {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        JFrame application = new JFrame();

        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.add(panel);
        application.setSize (250, 250);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And here is the class that draws to the JPanel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int drawCounter = 0; // counters for all the while statements

        int x1 = 0; // cords change with the while statemetns
        int x2 = 0;
        int y1 = 0;
        int y2 = 0;

        while (drawCounter <= 15)   //counter
        {
            y2 = 250;
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            x2 = x2 + 15;
            y1 = y1 + 15;
            drawCounter++;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You should also refer to the [really big index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html). You will find that the answers to most of your questions can be found there.